# how to use '-' minus sign in variable name for querying and printing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, variables, naming-conventions

I have been faced a problem and multiple instances and always tried renaming columns in case I get minus ('-') sign in column names / variable names.
Can somebody suggest how to circumvent or use minus '-' sign in variable name in python:

I get error as Python is unable to recognize "BU-1" and gives me an error.

```
df_bu_bu1.query('BU == @bu and "BU-1"== @country')
```

I even tried, without success:

```
df_bu_bu1.query("BU == @bu and 'BU-1'== @country")
```

Similarly face issues while printing the variable. 
df_bu_bu1 is a pandas dataframe and 'BU' and 'BU-1' are indexes.

Comment: What is `df_bu_bu1`? Is is a pandas DataFrame? (Say so explicitly, add a tag.)

Comment: Hi DYZ, can you suggest how to format the post! Thanks for formatting!

Comment: Yes, df_bu_bu1 is a pandas dataframe

Comment: Why not just do it the good old way? `df_bu_bu1[(df_bu_bu1["BU"]==bu) & (df_bu_bu1["BU-1"]== country)}`

Comment: thanks DYZ, I have been using the old good way all along.. looking a way so I can use 'BU-1' as a variable. In case there is anything possible. I looked on existing questions but mostly have bad ratings. Possibly old way is the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An awkward solution is to temporarily rename the offending columns:

```
df_bu_bu1.rename(columns={"BU-1": "BU1"})\
         .query("BU1==@country")\
         .rename(columns={"BU1": "BU-1"})
```

Looks like that's the best you can do.

Comment: any ideas how can we print 'BU-1' column. In few languages we can use '\' to mark a special character. Not sure how we treat this in Python!

Comment: Printing is easy: `df_bu_bu1["BU-1"]`.

Comment: Or `df_bu_bu1[:].rename(...).query(...)`.

Comment: As we have indexes - the work around is :  

df_bu_bu1.iloc[(df_bu_bu1.index.get_level_values('BU')==bu) & (df_bu_bu1.index.get_level_values('BU-1')==country)]

Comment: `df_bu_bu1.index.get_level_values('BU')` is the same as `df_bu_bu1.loc['BU']`